# Good service for collecting photos from many wedding guests?

Tags: photos, images, file-sharing

Many guests at my wedding took photos with their cameras and telephones. I'd like to get original-quality copies of all those images. Almost everyone has already started uploading them to Facebook, which would be perfect, but it reduces the image quality and the original is not downloadable.

**Is there an easy-to-use service that all my wedding guests can use to send me original-quality copies of their photos?**

I want to make it easy for them all. It can't be too complicated. It should just be browser-based rather than require a desktop application.

Answer (score 5):

[SeeYouThen](http://www.seeyouthen.com) is made specifically for this.  Great a an exchange for collecting photos, your friends are free to join.  Most of our couples collect between 700 to over 1000 photos.

Here's a unique twist about SeeYouThen it's not only for weddings, so if you like the concept you can do this for every party, reunion, family event, sports team, etc.

Let us know if we can help.  But it takes 2 minutes to create an exchange!

Comment: Seems good, but just so that people know, it's a paid service (50$/year) (which isn't that bad considering the price of a professional wedding photographer).

Comment: can you make it clear that you are affiliated with the website. I know you use "our" and "we" in the answer and your profile links to the website, but it's better if these things are 100% open.

Comment: No problem, just want to help.  FYI.  Its $4.95/month or $49.95/year for as many friends, family and guests you want. So if you have 200 guests at a wedding, typically if you plan for it you'll get 50 participants.

Answer (score 5):

Try [Picasa](http://picasa.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=153791&hl=en)

> Every album in Picasa Web Albums is
>   potentially collaborative. This means
>   you can open up your online albums so
>   [other people can contribute](http://picasa.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=157130)
>   photos and videos.
>
> *Adding contributors*
>
> Make an album collaborative by adding
>   contributors - individuals or entire
>   Google contact groups - in either
>   Picasa or Picasa Web Albums.
>   Contributors will need to sign in to
>   their Google Account to add photos.
>   Their content will be attributed to
>   them, and they can make edits such as
>   adding captions to, rotating, or even
>   deleting the pictures that they've
>   uploaded. Of course, as the owner of
>   the album, you have the ability to
>   edit this content as if it were your
>   own.

Answer (score 3):

I'd just ask people to email you the photos. Everyone has email, not everyone uses Flickr or another photo-management system.

Comment: Email attachment is a poor choice for many large files.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using something like Flickr. Your guests would need to have accounts, but if they use Yahoo, they should already be able to log in. Flickr saves the original copy as well as provides smaller copies, so you can pick and choose.

You should create an open group and let your guests upload to that group.

Comment: I used flickr for this exact purpose, but even with a pro account I don't think you have access to the full-res versions of photos uploaded to a (friended) free account.  Personally I think this isn't such a problem, since I can always ask for full-res versions of specific photos, but it's not what the question asked for.

Answer (score 2):

Dropbox perhaps? It uses a desktop application, sure, but it makes the process easy and probably quite pain-free.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a blog with [tumblr](http://tumblr.com) and enable user submissions. I believe the originals would be saved for you that way and the submissions can be anonymous. so your guests wouldn't require accounts.

Answer (score 1):

I work for a site called TheWeddingLens.com.  If you'd like to check it out, you can sign up for a free two-week trial and see if it's what you need.  We offer bulk uploads/downloads to groups via a unique URL and access code.  Bonus - it's wedding specific!

Answer (score 1):

The best thing i have found is to make everyone drop the images into a [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/home) folder. This is really easy and other people dont have to have their on account on dropbox.

Comment: Other users can view images without a dropbox account, but in order to add photos to the folder, they will need their own dropbox account.

Comment: You can use JotForm to let create a form where anybody (without an account) can upload files.

Answer (score 1):

With [albumpl.us](http://albumpl.us) you get all the photos instantly, at the source. Then you don't have to worry about getting the pics after.